# How to adjust placing of forms and image within a section in html?

Tags: html

My following code shows that both form and img tags are enclosed with in the same section tag.

[image: code]

But form is displayed ***above*** the img. As shown in the figure

[image: webpage image]

I want it to be displayed ***on*** the background img. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements are Block level meaning they will take up the entire width of the viewport. If you want it to float ontop of your image, either set the image as a background-image of the section, or even better, absolutely position the form over the top:

```
section {
  position: relative;
}
form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width; 100%;
}
```